# How can I get confidence and lift out of this Data (association rule)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a project to get support,confidence and lift out of the data (image posted)

I successfully get support by myself.

However, I have no idea how to get confidence and lift.

here is my code. I would be very thankful if you help me get confidence and lift

```
df=pd.read_csv('Groceries_dataset.csv')
df2=df.sort_values(by=['Member_number','Date'])
df2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhZhG.png)

```
unique_item=df2.drop_duplicates(['itemDescription'])
item=unique_item['itemDescription']
item_list=item.to_list()
item_list

count=0
for i in dict1.keys():
  count=count+1
count


### Support 
total=[]
for i in item_list:
  answer1=len(df2.loc[df2.itemDescription==str(i),:])/count
  total.append(answer1)

total
```

this is how I got support
But I really can't get confidence and lift by myself
I wish someone help me with my project

thx a lot.

Comment: What is actually meant by support, confidence and lift?